# How do I get YouTube statistics from the API in c#

Tags: c#, google-api, youtube-api, google-api-dotnet-client

How do I get YouTube video statistics? For example the: Likes, comment count, view count etc from the api.

The following code works but the returned values dont include the statistics.

According to the doc, I should be able to do :

```
var searchListRequest = youtubeService.Search.List("id,snippet,statistics");
```

but this returns an error.

The error am getting is:

> Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError statistics [400]
>   Errors[Message[statistics] Location[part -parameter]
>   Reason[unknownPart] Domain[youtube.part]]

The code is from [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list).

```
/*
*/   
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Upload;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;
using Google.Apis.YouTube.v3;
using Google.Apis.YouTube.v3.Data;

namespace Google.Apis.YouTube.Samples
{
  internal class Search
  {
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("YouTube Data API: Search");
      Console.WriteLine("========================");

      try
      {
        new Search().Run().Wait();
      }
      catch (AggregateException ex)
      {
        foreach (var e in ex.InnerExceptions)
        {
          Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.Message);
        }
      }

      Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
      Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private async Task Run()
    {
      var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
      {
        ApiKey = "REPLACE_ME",
        ApplicationName = this.GetType().ToString()
      });

      var searchListRequest = youtubeService.Search.List("snippet");
      searchListRequest.Q = "Google"; // Replace with your search term.
      searchListRequest.MaxResults = 50;

      // Call the search.list method to retrieve results matching the specified query term.
      var searchListResponse = await searchListRequest.ExecuteAsync();

      List<string> videos = new List<string>();
      List<string> channels = new List<string>();
      List<string> playlists = new List<string>();

      // Add each result to the appropriate list, and then display the lists of
      // matching videos, channels, and playlists.
      foreach (var searchResult in searchListResponse.Items)
      {
        switch (searchResult.Id.Kind)
        {
          case "youtube#video":
            videos.Add(String.Format("{0} ({1})", searchResult.Snippet.Title, searchResult.Id.VideoId));
            break;

          case "youtube#channel":
            channels.Add(String.Format("{0} ({1})", searchResult.Snippet.Title, searchResult.Id.ChannelId));
            break;

          case "youtube#playlist":
            playlists.Add(String.Format("{0} ({1})", searchResult.Snippet.Title, searchResult.Id.PlaylistId));
            break;
        }
      }

      Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Videos:\n{0}\n", string.Join("\n", videos)));
      Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Channels:\n{0}\n", string.Join("\n", channels)));
      Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Playlists:\n{0}\n", string.Join("\n", playlists)));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I have edited the question to add the error message. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you're using a valid API key and that you've enabled the YouTube Data API for your project. Also, double check that you're using an up-to-date version of the [.NET client library](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client).

Comment: Yes. Checked that. I also got the lastest version of the api from Nuget.

Comment: The `search` API doesn't let you query for statistics, maybe you meant to use the [videos.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#parameters) call instead? It looks like you want to get video statistics for 50 videos related to "Google", so you should use `search.list` to get that list of video IDs, then use `videos.list` for each ID to get the statistics for each video.

Answer (score 0):

I used your code given In the question and made it run by giving the API key and it ran successfully . hopefully there is something wrong with your key or application setting. Have you allowed Youtube and google API in your application setting . please make that thing sure